# PowerShell Manipulate grouped objects

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to create an updated baseball schedule with the teams and starting pitchers records. The first game stats should be team records 0-0 and pitchers records 0-0. So need to insert the records at first date and push other stats to next date

- Input file:

```
Date,Team,G,W,L,Pitcher,GP
4/13/2020,BAL,1,1,0,W.Johnson,1
4/16/2020,BAL,4,1,0,W.Johnson,2
4/14/2020,BAL,2,1,0,C.Mathewson,1
4/17/2020,BAL,5,0,1,C.Mathewson,2
4/15/2020,BAL,3,1,0,C.Young,1
4/13/2020,NYA,1,0,1,W.Ford,1
4/16/2020,NYA,4,0,1,W.Ford,2
4/14/2020,NYA,2,0,1,H.Pennock,1
4/17/2020,NYA,5,1,0,H.Pennock,2
4/15/2020,NYA,3,0,1,D.Dean,1
4/13/2020,KCM,1,1,0,S.Paige,1
4/18/2020,KCM,3,0,0,S.Paige,2
4/14/2020,KCM,2,0,1,J.Williams,1
4/13/2020,HOG,1,0,1,D.Redding,1
4/18/2020,HOG,3,0,0,D.Redding,2
4/14/2020,HOG,2,1,0,E.Rile,1
```

- Output file (90% works):

```
Date,Team,G,W,L,Pitcher,GP
,,,0,1,,
,,,1,0,,
4/13/2020,BAL,1,0,0,W.Johnson,1
4/13/2020,HOG,1,0,0,D.Redding,1
4/13/2020,NYA,1,0,0,W.Ford,1
4/13/2020,KCM,1,0,0,S.Paige,1
4/14/2020,HOG,2,0,0,E.Rile,1
4/14/2020,BAL,2,1,0,C.Mathewson,1
4/14/2020,NYA,2,0,1,H.Pennock,1
4/14/2020,KCM,2,0,0,J.Williams,1
4/15/20,KCM,1,0,1,J.Williams,1
4/15/20,HOG,1,1,0,E.Rile,1
4/16/20,BAL,1,1,0,C.Young,1
4/16/20,NYA,1,0,1,D.Dean,1
4/16/2020,NYA,4,0,1,W.Ford,2
4/16/2020,BAL,4,1,0,W.Johnson,2
4/17/2020,NYA,5,0,1,H.Pennock,2
4/17/2020,BAL,5,1,0,C.Mathewson,2
4/18/2020,HOG,3,0,1,D.Redding,2
4/18/2020,KCM,3,1,0,S.Paige,2
```

- Expected Output:

```
Date,Team,G,W,L,Pitcher,GP
4/13/2020,BAL,1,0,0,W.Johnson,1
4/13/2020,NYA,1,0,0,W.Ford,1
4/13/2020,KCM,1,0,0,S.Paige,1
4/13/2020,HOG,1,0,0,D.Redding,1
4/14/2020,BAL,2,1,0,C.Mathewson,1
4/14/2020,HOG,2,0,1,E.Rile,1
4/14/2020,NYA,2,0,1,H.Pennock,1
4/14/2020,KCM,2,1,0,J.Williams,1
4/15/2020,BAL,3,1,0,C.Young,1
4/15/2020,NYA,3,0,1,D.Dean,1
4/16/2020,BAL,4,1,0,W.Johnson,2
4/16/2020,NYA,4,0,1,W.Ford,2
4/18/2020,NYA,1,1,0,H.Pennock,2
4/18/2020,BAL,1,0,1,C.Mathewson,2
4/18/2020,KCM,3,0,1,S.Paige,2
4/18/2020,HOG,3,1,0,D.Redding,2
4/19/2020,KCM,1,0,0,S.Paige,2
4/19/2020,HOG,1,0,0,D.Redding,2
```

- Code:

```
$csv = Import-Csv 'C:\deployments\New folder\schedule1.txt' |
    Select-Object Date,Team, G, W, L, Pitcher, GP |
    Group-Object Team

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    if($_.Group[0].G -eq 1) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date    = $_.Group[0].Date
            Team    = $_.Group[0].Team
            G       = $_.Group[0].G
            W       = 0
            L       = 0
            Pitcher = $_.Group[0].Pitcher
            GP      = $_.Group[0].GP
        }
    }
    else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date    = $_.Group[0].Date
            Team    = $_.Group[0].Team
            G       = $_.Group[0].G
            W       = $_.Group[0].W
            L       = $_.Group[0].L
            Pitcher = $_.Group[0].Pitcher
            GP      = $_.Group[0].GP
        }
    }

    for ($ii = 1; $ii -lt $csv.Count; $ii++) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Date    = $_.Group[$ii].Date
            Team    = $_.Group[$ii].Team
            G       = $_.Group[$ii].G
            W       = $_.Group[$ii - 1].W
            L       = $_.Group[$ii - 1].L
            Pitcher = $_.Group[$ii].Pitcher
            GP      = $_.Group[$ii].GP
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Date    = Get-Date -Format 'M/dd/yy' -Date ([datetime]$_.Group[-1].Date).AddDays(1)
        Team    = $_.Group[-1].Team
        G       = $_.Group[0].G
        W       = $_.Group[-1].W
        L       = $_.Group[-1].L
        Pitcher = $_.Group[-1].Pitcher
        GP      = $_.Group[-1].GP
    }

} | Sort-Object Date | Export-Csv 'C:\deployments\New folder\schedule6.txt' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What is your actual powershell version? 4, 3, 2, 5.1 ?????

Comment: "Output file (90% works):" - what does the expected "Output file (100% works)" file look like? Also, your input file isn't sorted in date order per team - won't that mess up your ```for ( $ii = 1;...``` shuffling? Don't you need to sort the data by date *before* you ```group-object```? And, some of your output file dates seem to have adopted ```M/D/YY``` format instead of the original ```M/D/YYYY``` - is that a typo? Finally, I don't think you actually need to do ```Select-Object Date, ...```?

Comment: i sorted by date and now get the below, not understanding the first 2 lines. "Date","Team","G","W","L","Pitcher","GP"
,,,"0","0",,
,,,"0","0",,
"4/13/2020","BAL","1","0","0","W.Johnson","1"
"4/13/2020","NYA","1","0","0","W.Ford","1"
"4/13/2020","KCM","1","0","0","S.Paige","1"
"4/13/2020","HOG","1","0","0","D.Redding","1"
"4/14/2020","BAL","2","1","0","C.Mathewson","1"
"4/14/2020","HOG","2","0","1","E.Rile","1"
"4/14/2020","NYA","2","0","1","H.Pennock","1"
"4/14/2020","KCM","2","1","0","J.Williams","1"

Comment: 4/15/2020","BAL","3","1","0","C.Young","1"
"4/15/2020","NYA","3","0","1","D.Dean","1"
"4/16/2020","BAL","4","1","0","W.Johnson","2"
"4/16/2020","NYA","4","0","1","W.Ford","2"
"4/18/20","NYA","1","1","0","H.Pennock","2"
"4/18/20","BAL","1","0","1","C.Mathewson","2"
"4/18/2020","KCM","3","0","1","S.Paige","2"
"4/18/2020","HOG","3","1","0","D.Redding","2"
"4/19/20","KCM","1","0","0","S.Paige","2"
"4/19/20","HOG","1","0","0","D.Redding","2"

Comment: Can you post your *expected* output by editing your question rather than as comments (comments can be deleted at any time by moderators and housekeeping bots)

Comment: I think your expected output may have a couple of typos - it's potentially  missing ```4/17/2020,BAL,5,1,0,C.Mathewson,2``` and ```4/17/2020,NYA,5,0,1,H.Pennock,2``` - could you confirm?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Could those be the two at the top? >,,,0,1,,
>,,,1,0,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your approach kind of feels like a bit of an abuse of the pipeline, but I can't really come up with a more elegant solution.

In any case, if you make the following changes to your code it will give the required output:

#### Sample data

Rather than read from a file, I've used inline data so you can just cut & paste the code sample to play with it...

```
# set up some test data
$text = @"
Date,Team,G,W,L,Pitcher,GP
4/13/2020,BAL,1,1,0,W.Johnson,1
4/16/2020,BAL,4,1,0,W.Johnson,2
4/14/2020,BAL,2,1,0,C.Mathewson,1
4/17/2020,BAL,5,0,1,C.Mathewson,2
4/15/2020,BAL,3,1,0,C.Young,1
4/13/2020,NYA,1,0,1,W.Ford,1
4/16/2020,NYA,4,0,1,W.Ford,2
4/14/2020,NYA,2,0,1,H.Pennock,1
4/17/2020,NYA,5,1,0,H.Pennock,2
4/15/2020,NYA,3,0,1,D.Dean,1
4/13/2020,KCM,1,1,0,S.Paige,1
4/18/2020,KCM,3,0,0,S.Paige,2
4/14/2020,KCM,2,0,1,J.Williams,1
4/13/2020,HOG,1,0,1,D.Redding,1
4/18/2020,HOG,3,0,0,D.Redding,2
4/14/2020,HOG,2,1,0,E.Rile,1
"@
```

#### Sort the data before processing

You're bumping some of the data up or down a row for a given team, but you're not sorting it first so it's kind of random which date you're bumping it to.

If you sort the data first you'll be bumping it to the next chronological record rather than just to whatever date is next in the file for that team.

```
$csv = $text `
    | ConvertFrom-Csv `
    | Sort-Object Date ` # <-- sort the data
    | Select-Object Date, Team, G, W, L, Pitcher, GP `
    | Group-Object Team;
```

#### Correct the iteration limit

Change

```
    for ($ii = 1; $ii -lt $csv.Count; $ii++) {
        ... #             ^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

```
    for ($ii = 1; $ii -lt $_.Group.Count; $ii++) {
        ... #             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
```

`$csv.Count` is the number of groups (i.e. Teams) in the dataset, not the number of records for the current Team, which is represented by `$_.Group.Count`.

#### Correct the date format

```
        Date    = Get-Date -Format 'M/dd/yy' -Date ([datetime]$_.Group[-1].Date).AddDays(1)
        #                                ^^ - 2-digit year
```

should be

```
        Date    = Get-Date -Format 'M/dd/yyyy' -Date ([datetime]$_.Group[-1].Date).AddDays(1)
        #                                ^^^^ - 4-digit year
```

so you get the correct number of digits in the year.

#### Sort the result set

Not strictly necessary, but I added `Team` to the final `Sort-Object` to give this:

```
} | Sort-Object Date, Team | ConvertTo-Csv
```

According to some sources, the `Sort-Object` cmdlet isn't "[stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517793/what-is-stability-in-sorting-algorithms-and-why-is-it-important)" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11349063/3156906) so the one at the *top* of the script doesn't necessarily preserve the order of teams for the same date. Adding `Team` to the final `Sort-Object` ensures a predictable order of teams with the same date.

#### Result

If you make all these changes your output should be:

```
"Date","Team","G","W","L","Pitcher","GP"
"4/13/2020","BAL","1","0","0","W.Johnson","1"
"4/13/2020","HOG","1","0","0","D.Redding","1"
"4/13/2020","KCM","1","0","0","S.Paige","1"
"4/13/2020","NYA","1","0","0","W.Ford","1"
"4/14/2020","BAL","2","1","0","C.Mathewson","1"
"4/14/2020","HOG","2","0","1","E.Rile","1"
"4/14/2020","KCM","2","1","0","J.Williams","1"
"4/14/2020","NYA","2","0","1","H.Pennock","1"
"4/15/2020","BAL","3","1","0","C.Young","1"
"4/15/2020","NYA","3","0","1","D.Dean","1"
"4/16/2020","BAL","4","1","0","W.Johnson","2"
"4/16/2020","NYA","4","0","1","W.Ford","2"
"4/17/2020","BAL","5","1","0","C.Mathewson","2"
"4/17/2020","NYA","5","0","1","H.Pennock","2"
"4/18/2020","BAL","1","0","1","C.Mathewson","2"
"4/18/2020","HOG","3","1","0","D.Redding","2"
"4/18/2020","KCM","3","0","1","S.Paige","2"
"4/18/2020","NYA","1","1","0","H.Pennock","2"
"4/19/2020","HOG","1","0","0","D.Redding","2"
"4/19/2020","KCM","1","0","0","S.Paige","2"
```

which is a slightly different order to you "expected" results and has two additional rows which you confirmed are missing from your "expected".